# Share Point Multiple file transfer at once

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-api

I have a requirement where we need to move/copy multiple folder/file from one folder to another using **Share Point REST API'S** moving or copying one file at a time is possible, but is there a way to move/copy multiple folder/file from one folder to another?

this one i have used for single file transfer.
https://[abcxyz].sharepoint.com/_api/SP.MoveCopyUtil.MoveFileByPath()

```
`{
    "srcPath": {
        "__metadata": {
            "type": "SP.ResourcePath"
        },
        "DecodedUrl": "https://[abcxyz].sharepoint.com/Folder1/Book_Level_1.xlsx"
    },
    "destPath": {
        "__metadata": {
            "type": "SP.ResourcePath"
        },
        ]"DecodedUrl": "https://[abcxyz].sharepoint.com/Folder1/Folder2/Book_Level_1.xlsx"
    }
}`
```